# Ansible windows module or command to trim or change a string variable

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, windows-services

Need suggestion or idea on how to remove or get a sub string from a variable while running ansible playbook for windows.

Say I have a fact/variable which contains string like

```
"c:apps\Directory\sub_directoty"
```

Now I need to manipulate/trim this string and get a new fact/variable as string:

```
"c:apps\Directory\"
```

Do I need to use Powershell commands?

My purpose is, there is a windows service that is running from a different directory and I need to install the change on the directory the service is pointing too.

My playbook tasks to read and capture the path of service are accomplished using below:

```
tasks:
- name: Check if a service is installed
  win_service:
    name: ServerName 
  register: LINKServerInfo

- debug: msg="path is {{ LINKServerInfo.path }}"

- name: set linkpath  
  set_fact: linkpath="{{ LINKServerInfo.path }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can use "regex_replace" [Ansible Filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html)

For your case,

```
 `---
 - hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: false
   vars:
     a: 'c:apps\Directory\sub_directoty'
   tasks:
    - name: Replace
      set_fact: 
        b: "{{ a | win_dirname }}"
    - debug: msg="{{ b }}"
```

Output::
     `"msg": "c:apps\\Directory"`